# Is it possible to Implement youtube channels uploaded videos list into website?

Tags: php, html, youtube, implementation, youtube-api

What I want to do is, to show uploaded videos list of my youtube channel to website's visitors.

[image]

Something like that. (Image take from youtube channel, I want to show exactly this way)

Don't want to create iframe. Can I fetch data from channels exact page with PHP or something else? I have no idea if it's possible with youtube api. Any suggestions?

Comment: thx you. Now help to make it possible))

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The videos on a channel are essentially a user's so using the [YouTube GData API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html) you can make a call to `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=ahmednuaman` (my videos for example).